# Selenium NoSuchFrameException when waiting for combobox input

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I have an element that is placed in 2 frames. So I wait for the parent frame to load, switch to it, wait for the child frame to load, switch to it, then i try to access my element. The frame switching throws no error but when I try to access the element within the child frame, it is throwing an `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException` with no message.

```
    parentF = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "parent")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(parentF)
    childF = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "child")))
    driver.switch_to.frame(childF)

    program_select = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "xyz")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException
```

...implies that Selenium driven WebDriver instance was unable to locate the `<iframe>` element.

You have adapted the right approach. Ideally, to locate an iframe you have to induce `WebDriverWait inconjunction with expected_conditions set as frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it().`

However, there can be numerous reasons behind seeing this error and some of the reasons and solutions are as follows:

The desired iframe may be a nested iframe within it's parent iframe. In those cases you have to induce WebDriverWait first to switch to the parent iframe and then to the child iframe as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"parent_iframe_xpath")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"child_iframe_xpath")))
```

If you are switching between two sibling iframes then you first need to switch back to the default_content first and then switch to the sibling iframe as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"sibling_iframe_A")))
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"sibling_iframe_B")))
```

You can find a detailed discussion in How to address “WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: can't access dead object” and wait for a frame to be available using Selenium and Python

At times multiple iframes can have similar values for same attributes. In those cases, you may need to construct Locator Strategies which identifies the  element uniquely using the src attribute as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id="iframe_id and @src='iframe_src'"]")))
```